# Devise ignores client_options authorize path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I am using devise on rails 3.2 in combination with twitter as an omniauth strategy.
In order to login returning users without authorizing the app again I would like to make use of twitters authenticate method [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authenticate)
So I need to call "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate".

But devise is always using https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize even though I do set it explicitly in an initializer.

```
  config.omniauth :twitter, 'zsJ66OoLL1xmFNfDG+ifA', 'crRo2Gxi2wFmw3b3XXXXXX',
              :client_options => {:authorize_path => '/oauth/authenticate'}
```

Also the omniauth twitter gem is using "options.client_options.authorize_path = '/oauth/authenticate'" the authenticate url.
So I dont have a clue why devise is using the authorize url instead.

Does anybody know how to enforce the use of the authenticate URL?

## EDIT

Apparently this seems to be a twitter issue since I found out that twitter is doing the redirect to the authorize URL event though my user is still logged in at twitter..

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this post from twitter which explains the problem

Changes to the 'Sign in with Twitter' flow

> This change allows automatic redirection only for applications that request it. Applications that use /oauth/authenticate and rely on the automatic redirection behavior for logged-in users must enable this "Sign in with Twitter" option. If the option is not enabled, users will instead be directed to /oauth/authorize and will then be prompted to complete the application approval flow.

[link to post](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-to-sign-in-with-twitter)